# SugarCRM over SOAP - V2

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, axis, sugarcrm

We're using Apache Axis to generate client-side stubs to communicate with SugarCRM in a Java application.

As of a few days ago, we were using the WSDL file at http://.../soap.php?wsdl to generate our stubs. We found the version 2 WSDL file at http://.../services/v2/soap.php?wsdl, and out of necessity to delete relationships, we upgraded to the new version.

Prior to upgrading, calls to set_entry() would return a Set_entry_result, containing the status of the call, along with an Error_value indicating the status. We were able to use this to report/log the status of the set_entry() call.

Now, using v2, the set_entry() call returns a New_set_entry_result, whose only field is a String "id". This is very unhelpful, and we haven't found any documentation as to the purpose of the ID, nor have we found a way to establish the status of the call.

Is anyone familiar with the v2 SOAP API? Is it worth upgrading? If we shouldn't upgrade, is there any actual way to delete relationships using the v1 API? Various SugarCRM forum posts (this one in particular: http://panther.sugarcrm.com/forums/showthread.php?t=43871) suggest ways, but none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

ussualy you get the id of a new record in the reply. A lot of people have been complaining on the soap changes, so if this is your only option go with the upgrade.